# How do I get Rails' field syntax to match HTML rendered name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need my Rails code to render one of its form fields like this:

```
contacts[:custom_field][phone_number]
```

I've tried all sorts of things to get this to work in my template file:

```
:custom_field=> :phone_number
```

I get this in my HTML:

```
name="contacts[{:custom_field=>:license_1234, :class=>"text_field width_100_percent"}]"
```

and the ID should look like

```
id="helpdesk_ticket_custom_field_phone_number_50754"
```

But, when I submit my form, I get an error saying it can't connect to the API.

```
 Freshdesk::ConnectionError in Website::ContactsController#create

 Connection to the server failed. Please check hostname
```

WHen i do this in my console

```
  contacts.post_tickets(name: "John Doe", email: 'user@exmaple.net', :custom_field=>{:phone_number=>"123-123-1234"})
```

it works!  and posts but i cant seem to replicate this in my actualy code

html

```
= form_for(:contacts, url: contacts_path) do |f|
  = f.label "Name"
  %br
  = f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br    
  = f.label "Email"
  %br    
  = f.email_field :email, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Phone"
  %br    
  = f.text_field :custom_field=>{:phone_number_50754=>"AMD-123"}
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Question(s), and/or feedback"
  %br
  = f.text_area :description, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br
  = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

Comment: Can you show a more complete snippet from your template file?

Comment: @elevine - hey i added my form haml file

Comment: What is the full HTML element output that you want for your text field?

Comment: @elevine - <input class="text valid" id="contacts_custom_field_phone_number_50754" name="contacts[custom_field][phone_number_50754]" size="30" type="text">

Comment: @elevine - is that output what you were looking for?